# Java block not appearing

Tags: java, swing

Trying to make a game. Want a yellow block at the bottom of the screen, a dark grey (or black, doesnt really matter) bacground, and blue squares flying from the top of the screen at random times. Have been at it for awfully long but the blue squares do not appear, and I have no idea why. Im a beginner at Java, and have been through many resources - please advise, thanks!

Game Class Below

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.*;

public class Game extends JPanel {
    //THIS IS DISPLAY
    
    static int width = 1000;
    static int height = 700;
    
    int randNumb = 0;
    int squareWidth = 50;
    int squareHeight = 50;
    int squareYLocation = -squareWidth;
    boolean numberCreated = false;
    static boolean gameRunning = false;
    
    public Game() { 
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 700));

        
    }
    
    
    //generates a random Y value inside the window for the square to spawn at
    public void generateRandomNumber() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        randNumb = rand.nextInt(width - squareWidth);
        numberCreated = true;
    }
    


        
    
    public void paintComponent ( Graphics g )
      { 
        //int width  = getWidth();
        //int height = getHeight();
        
        //g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        
        super.paintComponent( g );
        //g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(randNumb, squareYLocation, squareWidth, squareHeight);
        
        
       g.setColor( Color.YELLOW );
        g.drawRect( 500, 600, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect(500, 600, 50, 50);
        
        //g.setColor(Color.blue);
        //g.fillRect(100, 200, 32, 32);
      } 
    
    
    public void update() {

        //calls the generateRandomNumber() method which gives the square a random x value inside the screen
        if (!numberCreated) {
            generateRandomNumber();
        }
        //moves the squares y coordinate towards the bottom of the screen and stops once it hits the bottom
        if (squareYLocation <= height) {
            squareYLocation++;

            //resets the x and y location to a new position
        } else {
            numberCreated = false;
            squareYLocation = -squareHeight;
        }
    }
    
    public void start() {
        gameRunning = true;
    }
    


            
        


}
```

Main

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
    
        
        //Constructor with frame title
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("words");
        //Makes frame visible
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //Size of frame & location
        frame.setBounds(240, 80, 1000, 700);
        //How to close the window
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Game());
                
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you Please add a picture of what does appear? Are just the blocks missing, or everything?

Comment: Eveyrhting appears but the blue rectangle. There is a black/dark gray background and a yellow square at the bottom center of the screen. Thanks!

Comment: I'll try adding an image as well!

Answer (score 2):

This statement means

```
int squareYLocation = -squareWidth;
```

that the Y position is -50 so the blue square will appear off screen. Make it 0 or positive

```
int squareYLocation = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! It appears now, but is not moving(like I want it to move from the top to the bottom). Thanks!

Comment: You need code to periodically update the coordinates. Have a look at this [Swing Timer intro](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)...